# Weighted average of time-series with changing weights over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, weighted-average

I need to generate a weighted average of the returns of some number of financial assets, where the weights used change over time. (The application is financial but the problem itself is a very general one).

Excerpts of my returns and weights are as follows:

**`returns_df`: Returns of assets over time**

```
┌──────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│     DateTime     │  Asset 1  │  Asset 2  │  Asset 3  │
├──────────────────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 2015-04-09 07:00 │ -0.000959 │ -0.000207 │ -0.000233 │
│ 2015-04-09 08:00 │ -0.004003 │  0.000169 │  0.001221 │
│ 2015-04-09 09:00 │ -0.000700 │ -0.000070 │ -0.000096 │
│ 2015-04-09 10:00 │ -0.000812 │ -0.000289 │  0.000177 │
│ 2015-04-09 11:00 │ -0.000030 │ -0.000168 │ -0.000315 │
└──────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

**`weights_df`: Weights of assets over time**

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Start of weights │ Asset 1 │ Asset 2 │ Asset 3 │
├──────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 2015-03-01       │       1 │       0 │       0 │
│ 2015-04-01       │   0.023 │  0.8733 │  0.1037 │
│ 2015-05-01       │       1 │       0 │       0 │
│ 2015-06-01       │  0.0477 │  0.8278 │  0.1245 │
└──────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

For example, the returns in the first table would all be weighted by `{0.023; 0.8733; 0.103}` as they all fall *after* `2015-04-01` but *before* `2015-05-01`.

My real data set has returns spanning the entire range of dates in my weights, of course.

I am not sure at all how to approach this, I thought of using `groupby()` but given that the shape of `weights_df` is not the same as `returns_df`, that doesn't seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
# alternatively try `import StringIO`

returns_datatext = StringIO("""
    DateTime     │  Asset 1  │  Asset 2  │  Asset 3
2015-04-09 07:00 │ -0.000959 │ -0.000207 │ -0.000233
2015-04-09 08:00 │ -0.004003 │  0.000169 │  0.001221
2015-04-09 09:00 │ -0.000700 │ -0.000070 │ -0.000096
2015-04-09 10:00 │ -0.000812 │ -0.000289 │  0.000177
2015-04-09 11:00 │ -0.000030 │ -0.000168 │ -0.000315
""")
returns_df = pd.read_table(returns_datatext, index_col=[0], parse_dates=True, sep='│')

weights_datatext = StringIO("""
Start of weights │ Asset 1 │ Asset 2 │ Asset 3
2015-03-01       │       1 │       0 │       0
2015-04-01       │   0.023 │  0.8733 │  0.1037
2015-05-01       │       1 │       0 │       0
2015-06-01       │  0.0477 │  0.8278 │  0.1245
""")
weights_df = pd.read_table(weights_datatext, index_col=[0], parse_dates=True, sep='│')
```

Expected results for the table above would be the following:

```
┌──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│     DateTime     │ Weighted average │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 2015-04-09 07:00 │        -0.000227 │
│ 2015-04-09 08:00 │         0.000182 │
│ 2015-04-09 09:00 │        -0.000087 │
│ 2015-04-09 10:00 │        -0.000253 │
│ 2015-04-09 11:00 │        -0.000180 │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) to link the two, and then `numpy.average`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## Fix whitespace in sample data
#returns_df.index.name = 'DateTime'
#returns_df.columns = ['Asset1', 'Asset2', 'Asset3']
#weights_df.index.name= 'Start of weights'
#weights_df.columns = ['Asset1', 'Asset2', 'Asset3']

df = pd.merge_asof(returns_df, weights_df,
                   left_index=True, right_index=True, 
                   direction='backward',
                   suffixes=['', '_weight'])

cols = ['Asset1', 'Asset2', 'Asset3']
returns_df['weighted_average'] = np.average(df[cols], weights=df[[col + '_weight' for col in cols]], axis=1)
```

#### Output: `returns_df`

```
                       Asset1    Asset2    Asset3  weighted_average
DateTime                                                           
2015-04-09 07:00:00 -0.000959 -0.000207 -0.000233         -0.000227
2015-04-09 08:00:00 -0.004003  0.000169  0.001221          0.000182
2015-04-09 09:00:00 -0.000700 -0.000070 -0.000096         -0.000087
2015-04-09 10:00:00 -0.000812 -0.000289  0.000177         -0.000253
2015-04-09 11:00:00 -0.000030 -0.000168 -0.000315         -0.000180
```

---

For illustration, this is the resulting `DataFrame` from the merge. The logic chooses the closest date in `weights_df` which is before the date in `returns_df` as the merge condition:

```
                       Asset1    Asset2    Asset3  Asset1_weight  Asset2_weight  Asset3_weight
DateTime                                                                                      
2015-04-09 07:00:00 -0.000959 -0.000207 -0.000233          0.023         0.8733         0.1037
2015-04-09 08:00:00 -0.004003  0.000169  0.001221          0.023         0.8733         0.1037
2015-04-09 09:00:00 -0.000700 -0.000070 -0.000096          0.023         0.8733         0.1037
2015-04-09 10:00:00 -0.000812 -0.000289  0.000177          0.023         0.8733         0.1037
2015-04-09 11:00:00 -0.000030 -0.000168 -0.000315          0.023         0.8733         0.1037
```

Comment: Beautiful! Noticed the `reset_index()` were not needed if you used `left_index=True` and `right_index=True` instead, given both datasets had the datetime's as indices.

Comment: @Doggie52 great catch.

Comment: Actually the `np.average` is not the right method to use here. The weights will change over time, however it seems to me like it accepts only a fixed set of weights provided.

Comment: @Doggie52 you misunderstand. The `merge_asof` step takes care of matching the appropriate weights based on the time. Then `numpy.average` is computed along `axis=1`, meaning that for each row it uses the specified weights. Just in the sample you provided, that turns out to always be the same weighting.

Comment: To show a concrete example, If you have a `DataFrame` with the same data but different weights: `df = pd.DataFrame({'data1': [1,1],'data2': [2,2],'weight1': [1,1], 'weight2': [1,5]})` the average is different for each row: `np.average(df[['data1', 'data2']], weights=df[['weight1', 'weight2']], axis=1)` will output `array([1.5, 1.83333333])`

Comment: Correct - apologies. My error came from a different part of my code. FYI you can use `np.ma.average()` if some of the weight rows sometimes sum to zero. I believe otherwise the function is the same as `np.average()`.